# How to combine two data into one in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm getting the data from two different place.
After getting the data, how to merge two into one.
For example;

```
//data structure looks like:
//from url1
{
    "data": [
                {
            "id": 7,
            "email": "michael.lawson@reqres.in",
            "first_name": "Michael",
            "last_name": "Lawson"
        },
    ]
}

//from url2
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 8,
            "email": "lindsay.ferguson@reqres.in",
            "first_name": "Lindsay",
            "last_name": "Ferguson"
        }
    ]
}
```

after the merge, I would like the data looks like:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 7,
            "email": "michael.lawson@reqres.in",
            "first_name": "Michael",
            "last_name": "Lawson"
        },
        {
            "id": 8,
            "email": "lindsay.ferguson@reqres.in",
            "first_name": "Lindsay",
            "last_name": "Ferguson"
        }
    ]
}
```

code:

```
 const url1 = "https://reqres.in/api/users"; 
 const url2 = "https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2";

//store the data from url1
const data1 = fetch(url1).then(result=>{
return result.data;
})

//store the data from url2
const data2 = fetch(url2).then(result=>{
return result.data;
})
```

I've tried the Object.assign(),but it seems like it does not work

```
const data = Object.assign(data1, data2);  // it only get the data from data1, the data2 is missing
console.log(data);
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you want the data to look like? "merge two into one" is a little too vague.

Comment: Looks like you want `const data = [...data1, ...data2];`

Comment: @jabaa not work for me.  the `const data = [...data1, ...data2];` makes the error `Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance`

Comment: you need to use first  a [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Comment: If `data1` is of the form `{data: [ ... ]}`, then you need to spread `...data1.data`, not `...data1`.

Comment: @Tim you not get data correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to merge promises resolving to arrays. You have to await the promise and can use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to merge the elements. You have to use the `json` method to read and parse the response. It also returns a promise. I wrapped the `await`s in an async [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) because you can't use `await` in a non-async functions or in global scope.

```js
const url1 = "https://reqres.in/api/users"; 
const url2 = "https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2";

// store promise to data from url1
const data1 = fetch(url1)
              .then(result => result.json())
              .then(result => result.data);

// store promise to data from url2
const data2 = fetch(url2)
              .then(result => result.json())
              .then(result => result.data);

(async () => {
  const data = [...await data1, ...await data2];
  console.log(data); 
})();
```

Comment: It works . The example I showed that is missing the `result => result.json()` part, but actually the problem is the async. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

try this

```js
 const url1 = "https://reqres.in/api/users"; 
     const url2 = "https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2";

    //store the data from url1
    async function getData(){

        
    let response1 = await fetch(url1);
    let response2 = await fetch(url2);

    
    if (response1.status === 200 && response2.status === 200) {
        const data1 = await response1.json();
        const data2 = await response2.json();
        // handle data

        const data = [...data1.data, ...data2.data];  // it only get the data from data1, the data2 is missing
        console.log(data); 
    }




    }

    getData();
```

Answer (score 1):

My approach would be:

1. Put the urls in an array.
2. Use [`async/await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await) to make the process easier.
3. [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the array to create a new array of promises.
4. `await` until all the promises have been resolved.
5. Parse the JSON to JS objects.
6. Return an object that combines all the data properties of the objects within one data property with [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap).

```js
const urls = ['https://reqres.in/api/users','https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2'];

// Pass in the array to the function
async function getData(urls) {

  try {

    // `map` over the array to create an array of promises
    const promises = urls.map(url => fetch(url));

    // Wait for the responses to return
    const responses = await Promise.all(promises);

    // Use `map` again to parse the JSON
    // `.json()` returns a new promise so we have to
    //  use `Promise.all` again to wait for them all to resolve
    const data = await Promise.all(responses.map(res => res.json()));

    // Finally return an object that combines the data
    // within one data property
    return { data: data.flatMap(obj => obj.data) };
  
  } catch(err) {
    return err;
  }

}

(async () => {
  console.log(await getData(urls));
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

To combine all the elements of 2 arrays together, you can use the spread operator like

```js
const data = [...data1.data, ...data2.data];
```

or you can use the [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) function:

```js
const data = data1.data.concat(data2.data);
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you fetch data is not complete.

This code below will give you a Response object that contain some infomation about response you got.

```
fetch('https://reqres.in/api/users').then(response => console.log(response))
```

But to retrieve data correctly, You should do like this:

```
fetch('https://reqres.in/api/users').then(response => response.json()).then(data => console.log(data))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
//data structure looks like:
//from url1
const url = {
    "data": [
                {
            "id": 7,
            "email": "michael.lawson@reqres.in",
            "first_name": "Michael",
            "last_name": "Lawson"
        },
    ]
}

//from url2
const urlTwo = {
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 8,
            "email": "lindsay.ferguson@reqres.in",
            "first_name": "Lindsay",
            "last_name": "Ferguson"
        }
    ]
}

let data = [...url.data, ...urlTwo.data];
console.log(data);
```

Try to do this:

```
//data structure looks like:
//from url1
const url = {
    "data": [
                {
            "id": 7,
            "email": "michael.lawson@reqres.in",
            "first_name": "Michael",
            "last_name": "Lawson"
        },
    ]
}

//from url2
const urlTwo = {
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 8,
            "email": "lindsay.ferguson@reqres.in",
            "first_name": "Lindsay",
            "last_name": "Ferguson"
        }
    ]
}

let data = [...url.data, ...urlTwo.data];
console.log(data);
```

If you need help, pls tell me

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.